# Can the magnetic flux inside a material increase even if the material is already saturated?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have the following problem: 
I simulated a construction of two magnets with an angle of around 30 degrees and Vanadium Permendur between them.

Vanadium Permendur should have a Saturation Induction of 2.3 T but my simulation using FEMM  shows even higher levels of 2.4 Tesla or more.

Is it possible to increase the magnetic flux inside the material beyond the saturation? or is FEMM just wrong? (using the windows program)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be that FEMM extrapolates the B-H curve too much (beyond the valid range). But I am not sure and would love to hear what others say.

My simulation (see below) shows a B-field exceeding 6 T which seems too high. The material (Supermalloy) is saturated at 0.8 T according to some source.

FEMM problem:

[image: FEMM problem]

Solution (with over 6.0 T):

[image]